# Query not working on left join?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following query which gives me result with `single` marstat.

```
SELECT
  a_event . *,
  members.*  
FROM a_event
  INNER JOIN members
    ON (members.mem_id = a_event.a_uid)
  LEFT JOIN `profiles`
    ON (profiles.mem_id = members.mem_id
        AND profiles.marstat =  'Single')
WHERE a_event.a_event_id = '5496'
    AND members.gender = 'm'
    AND a_event.a_fb_event_id = '0'
```

But the actual situation is that a_event member must match with member table (INNER JOIN is compulsory) then this result will match with profiles table 's mem_id having marital status as single . But the main problem is profile table may contain result with profiles.mem_id or no entry so that user from a_event.mem_id if not present in profiles.mem_id then that user will also be considered as `single`

Please help
thanks

Comment: so you want the result to show everyone, even if they don't have a profile - and if they don't to be automatically considered single?

Comment: Yes , if user a_event.mem_id with (where condition) is single or his/her record is not present in profiles then it must be returned .But here `Married` ppl are also returning in result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want a row to be returned when:

a) the user has a profile and is single
b) the user has no profile

In that case the query should be:

```
SELECT
  a_event . *,
  members.*  
FROM a_event
  INNER JOIN members
    ON (members.mem_id = a_event.a_uid)
  LEFT JOIN `profiles`
    ON (profiles.mem_id = members.mem_id)
WHERE a_event.a_event_id = '5496'
    AND members.gender = 'm'
    AND a_event.a_fb_event_id = '0'
    AND (profiles.marstat =  'Single' OR profiles.marstat IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

without a fiddle it's hard to test, but try this: updated answer with fiddle

```
    SELECT
      a_event . *,
      members.*  
    FROM a_event
      INNER JOIN members
        ON (members.mem_id = a_event.a_uid)
      LEFT JOIN `profiles`
        ON (profiles.mem_id = members.mem_id)
    WHERE a_event.a_event_id = '5496'
        AND members.gender = 'm'
        AND a_event.a_fb_event_id = '0'
        AND (profiles.marstat =  'Single' or is null)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99b774/3

Comment: no this query is not helpful.. Let me upload on sqlfiddle

Comment: Hi wribit I have developed sql schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4c09/1. Please check and let me know

Comment: please look at this fiddle - the a_id field in the events table was set to an incorrect member id. as well, I changed the query to match mine - and it seems to work - just realized it should return an empty profile as well... working on it

Comment: but if I remove entry of 999 from profiles table then result is not is displaying.